# Custom control binding to a collection within a property

Tags: templates, custom-controls, binding

I stuggeling with the databinding with in a custom control

I've got some properties within my custom control.

```
public static DependencyProperty TitleProperty;
public static DependencyProperty PageDictionaryProperty;

public string Title
{
    get
    {
        return (string)base.GetValue(TitleProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        base.SetValue(TitleProperty, value);

    }

}

public Innax.ManualParts.PageDictionary PageDictionary
{
    get
    {
        return (Innax.ManualParts.PageDictionary)base.GetValue(PageDictionaryProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        base.SetValue(PageDictionaryProperty, value);
    }

}
```

binding to the table isn't a problem. this works fine

but now i want to bind to the keyword property within the pageDictionary.

```
public class PageDictionary
{
    //some other properties....
    public List<string> Keywords
    {
        get
        {
            return GetKeyWords();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the XAML file.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InnaxBook" >
    <Style x:Key="alternatingWithTriggers" 
               TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HelpTopicLineTemplate">
        <Border x:Name="HelpTopicLine">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="{Binding DictionaryName}" Width="25px" x:Name="btnGoto" ></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Manual}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Manual}" >
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions >
                                <Label x:Name="TitleControl" Content="{TemplateBinding Title }"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="Aqua" ></Label>
                                <StackPanel x:Name="IndexContainer" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"  Orientation="Vertical" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                                    <Label Height="30" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{TemplateBinding IndexLabelText}" />
                                    <ListView  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <Button Height="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Content="knoppie" />
                                    </ListView>

                                    <ItemsControl ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingWithTriggers}" 
                                            AlternationCount="2" 
                                            x:Name="RelatedItemsControl" 
                                            Grid.Row="1"
                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                            ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding PageDictionary}"
                                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HelpTopicLineTemplate}">
                                    </ItemsControl>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

if anyone could help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

In your case the PageDirectory class need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Each time the keyword inside changed you need to raise a PropertyChanged event like this:

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Keywords"))
```

The binding string then will have view like this:

```
{Binding Keywords, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:PageDictionary}}}
```

Where local is namespace declared upper in the xaml for access PageDictionary type.